# NSDateFormatter wrong date

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

As simple as

```
     NSDateFormatter *df  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
     NSLog(@"Current date in event %@ %@",currentDate,[df stringFromDate:currentDate]);
```

But in the log

```
    Current date in event 2013-10-01 22:00:00 +0000 02/10/2013
```

Why?

Comment: It looks right to me if your timezone is two or more hours ahead of UTC time (which it is since you are in Italy).

Comment: Why? Why printing currentDate is different from printing out stringFromDate: ? the problem is the day: there is 1 day difference!

Comment: Run it in the morning and there will be no day difference

Comment: Ok. My question is very simple: how to make the [df stringFromDate] == currentDate ??

Comment: It is the same. Don't be confused by the output of logging an `NSDate` object. It is simply a difference in timezones used to display the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you log an `NSDate` it always prints in UTC time. When you use `stringFromDate:` you get a date in local time unless you change the timezone of the date formatter.

In this case you are in a timezone two hours ahead of UTC (assuming you are in Italy).

Since the `NSDate` object is October 1, 2013 at 22:00 UTC, this is the same as midnight of October 2, 2013 at UTC+2. This is why you see the string showing October 2.

Here's another way to look at it. You are not seeing a 1 day difference. You are actually seeing a 2 hour difference due to your timezone. From midnight to 0200 hours your time, you will see what appears to be a 1 day difference.

Comment: dates in iOS are a very headache!