# Calendar -isDateInToday:date 00:15 not in today?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to compare if a time is in today. I used the NSCalendar `[Calender isDateInToday:date]` method. However, a time just passed midnight fail the test.
Time 00:14:05 returns NO but 21:43:47 returns YES.

My test code:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian]; 
NSLog(@"date: %@, isInToday: %i, Currernt date: %@", o.deliverDate, [cal isDate:o.deliverDate inSameDayAsDate:[TimeIntervals getCurrerntLocalTime]], [TimeIntervals getCurrerntLocalTime]);
```

where`[TimeIntervals getCurrerntLocalTime]` returns current local system time:

```
+(NSDate *)getCurrerntLocalTime{
NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];
return destinationDate;
}
```

And result is:

```
date: 2015-02-09 00:14:05 +0000, isInToday: 0, Currernt date: 2015-02-09 19:07:43 +0000
date: 2015-02-09 21:43:47 +0000, isInToday: 1, Currernt date: 2015-02-09 19:07:44 +0000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're getting bit by the timezone somehow, but it's hard to say how since you don't show us how you set things up.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for your reply. I have updated the `[TimeIntervals getCurrerntLocalTime]` implementation. However I have printed out both time that I am comparing, it is obviously that 2015-02-09 00:14:05 should be in the same day of 2015-02-09 19:07:43

Comment: Why, for current local time, do you not simply do `[NSDate date]`?

Comment: (You do not understand how NSDate deals with timezones.  I'd suggest you study that a bit.  Consider that your NSCalendar is interpreting the time values in the local timezone.)

Comment: [NSDate date] gives me UTC time. And the method I used is a solution from StackOverflow. But my problem is that the `isDate:date inSameDayAsDate:otherDate` method returns NO for 00:14:05 and 19:07:43

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122239/nsdateformatter-wrong-date

Answer (score 6):

You should take your current Calendar:

In swift:

```
let isToday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInToday(date)
```